# Web API send multiple objects via jQuery POST

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API controller that accepts an Inspection model, i.e.

```
public class Inspection
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

and I have create a POST method on the controller. This works fine and I have tested it with jQuery.

In my javascript page I create an Inspection, i.e.

```
var inspection = {
    ID: '123456'
};
```

and then do $.ajax like this:

```
var p = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://...',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(item),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

So my question is: if I have multiple inspections to post, how do I send them all to the controller either in one batch or in single batches?

Comment: Can you post your API controller and its action method? Also, instead of relying on the model binding to a List<Inspection> have you tried using a method that accepts HttpRequestMessage and then parsed the request content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST'ing multiple integers in a single call should be easy to do. A few quick things to check:

1. In your controller, does your method signature look something like:

   ```
   public void Post([FromBody]int[] values) { // code here }
   ```

   Note the use of the [FromBody] attribute.
2. In your POST, is the content type header set to "**Content-Type: application/json**"?

Comment: I'm going to give you an upvote and the accepted answer because part of my problem was that I wasn't setting Content-Type as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, Depending on what your server is expecting, something like this might work:

```
var itemArr = [inspection0, inspection1, inspection2]; // etc...

var p = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://...',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(itemArr),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        //do stuff
    }
}).fail(function(data) {
    // handle failure
});
```

Or, to send in multiple batches:

```
var i = 0,
    max = itemArr.length;

for (; i < max; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://...',
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(itemArr[i]),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // handle failure
    });
}
```

Also, it's probably a good idea to add a `.fail(...)` handler, as well.

Comment: Just tried this and the controller isn't interpreting the data correctly.

Comment: @markp3rry Any luck with my update? (Splitting into multiple HTTP calls.) Could you change the method you have configured to the 'POST' verb to accept IEnumerable<Inspection> or List<Inspection> as the parameter?

Comment: @markp3rry I didn't realize this question related to ASP.net. Let me know if my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: tried doing pretty much what you suggested. The ajax request is hitting the 'success' part but the List<inspections> in the web service method is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [jQuery.json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) plugin for this kind of situation in the past.

Here's [an example I found](http://forums.asp.net/t/1517358.aspx/1) on how you can use it to send multiple items in a single AJAX call:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function savePayment() {
    //Creating some test data
    var lineItems = new Object();
    lineItems.Entrys = new Array();
    lineItems.Entrys[0] = new Object({ Approved: "1.0", Deductible: "1.0", Coinsurance: "1.0", PaymentAmount: "1.0", VisitId: "1.0", VisitChargeId: "1.0" });
    lineItems.Entrys[1] = new Object({ Approved: "2.0", Deductible: "2.0", Coinsurance: "2.0", PaymentAmount: "2.0", VisitId: "2.0", VisitChargeId: "2.0" });


    //Posting them to server with ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: '<%=Url.Action("SavePayment", "Home") %>',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $.toJSON(lineItems),
      success: function(result) {
        if (result) {
          alert('Success');
        }
        else {
          alert('Failure');
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I will give it a go in the morning. It looks like you're posting back to a 'classic' controller and not a Web API one - am I correct or not?

Comment: @markp3rry Yes, this example isn't for Web API. The goal was mainly to show you how you could bundle multiple `Inspection` objects together and use `jQuery.json` to bundle them together to send them in a single POST.